# How to identify the menu item clicked

Tags: primefaces

I am using Primefaces' (version 4) menu.

When a menu is clicked, the user is navigated to the respective page. In the page, I need to identify which menu item was clicked.

The reason is that a single page is mapped to multiple menu items & I need to identify the menu item which was clicked. How can it be identified ?

Code:

```
<p:menu model="#{menuBean.model}" />
```

**MenuBean.java**

```
public class MenuBean {

    private MenuModel model;

    public MenuBean() {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();

        DefaultSubMenu firstSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Submenu");

        DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("External");
        item.setUrl("http://www.primefaces.org");
        item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");
        firstSubmenu.addElement(item);

    }

    public MenuModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than call `setURL()` you can call `setCommand()` with the parameter being the name of the method to call and passing it a parameter indicating the menu identifier. Have a look here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf on how to use `setCommand()`.

Define your menu item like this:

```
public MenuBean() {
    ...
    DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("Save");  
    item.setIcon("ui-icon-disk");  
    item.setCommand("#{menuBean.doCommand('m1')}");
    firstSubmenu.addElement(item);
    ...
}

public void doCommand(String identifier) {
   ...
}
```